# jest test async function recieving undefined

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs

Hi I'm trying to test a post route that make loots of operations using Jest.

I'm trying to mock a class that makes a http call to another API. The problem is the response is always undefined and I have no idea whats wrong.

This is my mock comunicante-service.js (located in root/**mock**):

```
module.exports = {
  getConfig: jest.fn(async () => {
    Promise.resolve(dadosContaConfig);
  }),
  sendMessage: jest.fn(async () => {
    Promise.resolve('ok');
  }),
};
```

And that's the test

```
jest.mock('../src/services/comunicante-service');

describe('test /message', () => {
  it('no token', async () => {
    const res1 = await request(app).post('/message').set(config);

    expect(res1.statusCode).toEqual(400);
});
```

inside of the code that handle the /result there's a call to

```
const aux = await comunicanteService.getConfig(conta_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have forgotten to return something from the mock service. You could try:

```js
module.exports = {
  getConfig: jest.fn(async () => {
    return Promise.resolve(dadosContaConfig);
  }),
  sendMessage: jest.fn(async () => {
    return Promise.resolve('ok');
  }),
};
```

This can be simplified to:

```js
module.exports = {
  getConfig: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(dadosContaConfig),
  sendMessage: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('ok'),
};
```

Comment: keep getting undefined, I've had put a console.log inside the function and had no print of it. So there's something wrong before even the call